# How to fix Rails 'ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Program without an ID)'

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs

I am doing an initial test of my Rails API by performing a fetch to my backend and using console.log() to view the results in my browser console. My error appears when I make the request to my namespaced url to see a list of programs.

I have checked the controller show method, as well as my routes and model. I know that it is returning html instead of JSON and that is why the fetch is breaking in part.

App.js

```
componentDidMount(){
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/programs')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json))
```

programs_controller.rb

```rb
class Api::V1::ProgramsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @programs = Program.all
    render json: @programs
  end

  def show
    @program = Program.find(params[:id])
    render json: @program
  end

  private

  def program_params
    params.require(:program).permit(:url, :name, :network, :image)
  end
end
```

I expected to see a list of 18 programs I placed in my seeds.rb file but I get the error from ActiveRecord that says 'Couldn't find Program without an ID'. I did try passing :id into the .permit() in my program_params method but had no luck there either.

Comment: Is the show action giving you the error or the index action?

Comment: It's the show action, which is weird. I checked rake routes and I don't have an index path, which I found a tad strange.

Comment: It is strange that it doesn't find an index path yes, I don't see any odd things. Do you add an id behind the fetch url like this: http://localhost:3000/api/v1/programs/1 for the show action?

Comment: I left an 's' off resources in my nested routes. @Changwoo Rhee had to point that out. Can't believe I spent 3hrs on that one! Lol

Comment: Oh man, I also checked your routes file on github but didn't even spot that haha. Great that it's solved now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your api/v1 url will be miss in routes.rb or something wrong. Can you show me your routes.rb file?

> additionally
>   i have checked your source code in github 
>   after you write comment to this answer
>   and I find wrong word
>   you have coding resource in routes.rb and it's wrong word
>
> you have to change **resource** to **resources** in config/routes.rb
>
> 2.5 Singular Resources
>   Sometimes, you have a resource that clients always look up without referencing an ID. For example, you would like /profile to always show the profile of the currently logged in user. In this case, you can use a singular resource to map /profile (rather than /profile/:id) to the show action:

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources

I recommend you have to read rails guides
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/

Comment: Tried to add code but it came out jumbled. Here's a link to the file [link]https://github.com/koberlander/tv-list-backend/blob/master/config/routes.rb[link].

Comment: "resource" is not equal "resources"

Comment: I can't believe I left the 's' off of that! :facepalm: